# Get count query results with ignoring the LIMIT statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple query as follows:

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM blah WHERE disabled = '0'";
```

Now for pagination, I need to add `LIMIT` to my query, so:

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM blah WHERE disabled = '0' LIMIT 10,20";
```

And still, I want to know about the number of all rows with `mysql_num_rows`, but in the above query it is always 10, since I'm limiting the results, so for the number of all rows I need to do the same query again without `LIMIT` statement.

And it's somehow stupid to run the same query twice to just get the number of all rows, anybody has a better solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

MySQL [supports a `FOUND_ROWS()` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) to find the unlimited number of rows that would have been returned from the previous limited query.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM blah WHERE disabled = '0'  LIMIT 10,20
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

Note that (a) you need to include the `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` option, and (b) that this is a specific MySQL extension that won't work on another RDBMS (though they each *may* have their own way of doing this.)

This isn't necessarily the best way of doing things, even if it might feel like it; you still have to issue two statements, you're introducing non-standard SQL, and the actual `COUNT`ing is likely to be a similar speed to a simple `SELECT COUNT(*)...` anyway. I'd be inclined to stick to the standard way of doing it, myself.

Comment: My real query is like: `SELECT members.username, stock.id FROM members JOIN stock ON members.id = stock.user_owner LIMIT 10`, where would I put the `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` in this query?

Comment: Right after the `SELECT`: `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS members.username, stock.id ...`

Comment: For those who're reading this, to get the count you'll need this after the query: `$count = mysql_query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()"); $count = mysql_result($count , 0); echo $count;`

Comment: But bear in mind that [the mysql_ functions are deprecated and should no longer be used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Comment: I dont know why but for me `FOUND_ROWS()` returning `1`. Nothing else. `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS log.suma, ...blabla... FROM log INNER JOIN kategorie 
ON log.id_kategorie = kategorie.id WHERE ( kategorie.kategoria LIKE "%a%" ) 
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 7;

SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as pocet`

Comment: As of MySQL 8.0.17 `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` query modifier is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

For pagination, you have to run a count query to get the total first.

```
$q = "SELECT count(*) FROM blah WHERE disabled = '0'";
```

Two queries are **necessary**.

Comment: this is again running 2 queries, right? one for the real results and one for the count

Comment: @behz4d Yes, as i said, 2 queries are necessary.

Comment: It seems it's not, `https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows`

Answer (score 1):

You need two queries if you want to know the total results, but `COUNT` ignore `LIMIT` so, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM blah WHERE disabled = '0' LIMIT 10,20 // Give 10 rows 

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM blah WHERE disabled = '0' LIMIT 10,20 // Give you a count of ALL records
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$total = "SELECT count(*) FROM blah WHERE disabled = '0'";

if($total > 0)
{
    $q = "SELECT * FROM blah WHERE disabled = '0' LIMIT 0,10";
}
```

it's better to include a pagination class and call the LIMIT and OFFSET dynamically.

Comment: If you want i will share you the pagination scripts.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this,

first you can cache the total rows if you know that your data does not 
change alot - not a very good sollution, I don't like it at least.

secondly you may want to have a look at `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` but sometimes COUNT(*) is faster
because first one will scan the full table while count will scan the index. It's up to you
to test and use what ever you wish.

If you don't have lots of data `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` will be a good sollution.